# Adding hyperlinks to questions/answers on mobile site

Tags: support, feature-request

I tend to use the mobile site a lot, but it’s missing a few of the really helpful desktop features (i.e. adding hyperlinks (with neat/concise anchor text), bulleting, etc.) I also can’t use the app, because storage space...

Would it be possible to add an “Insert Hyperlink” function for the mobile site? I’ve been trying with HTML [a href=“...”], but it’s not displaying neatly, and I’d like to give my posts half a chance of looking tidy.

Equally, if I’m missing something really obvious, I’d love to know!

Comment: For a post, can you not use the normal `[text text text](URL)` form?

Comment: I find it easier to just type the brackets than to use the toolbar.  Note that the toolbar is never present in *comments* anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Use the markdown

When editing/answering/questioning on the desktop version you can see a little help/question mark button at the top right corner of the field where you write something. This gives you plenty of information about how to write stuff in posts on the site.

*Please do not use HTML if there is a way around it - HTML regularly messes with the markdown. Try to get used to using MarkDown without the features (at least as a workaround).*

Here is an example fo you with the links:

You can write a link to [the MarkDown help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/editing-help) the following way:

```
[the MarkDown help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/editing-help)
```

In the same way you can accomplish

- a list
- in multiple ways

This would be accomplished like this:

```
- a list  
- in multiple ways
```

For a numbered list

1. which would
2. look like this

you would write:

```
1. which would
2. look like this
```

A header is

```
# Header level 1
## Header level 2
### Header level 3
```

And emphasis is

```
*italic*
**bold**
```

There are quite a few more things that you can find in the linked help menu. If you are regularly posting stuff it's worth it to try and learn it. It makes stuff a lot faster and easier if you don't have to rely on the little buttons.

Comment: Thank you! I can’t find the help menu on the mobile site, so haven’t been able to remember “MarkDown” in order to search for it - much appreciated.

Comment: @K.Price just `edit` some post to see how it’s done (and don’t click Save).